# Progressive cart item custom shipping cost in Woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, product-quantity, shipping-method

I need to figure out a way to do woocommerce shipping rates based on items on cart.
I need to charge 120 if buying 1-2 items and 180 buying 3. I added a free shipping option for 4+ (based on $)

I tried adding this to the flat rate price: 120+60([qty]-2) it works in all instances but the 1 item, because it charges $60.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With the following code, you will be able to get this shipping rates: 
- 1 or 2 items: $120 
- 3 items: $180 
- 4 items or more: Free shipping (hiding flat rate method)

1) Add the following code to function.php file of your active child theme (active theme):

```
add_filter('woocommerce_package_rates', 'custom_progressive_shipping_costs', 10, 2);
function custom_progressive_shipping_costs( $rates, $package ){

    $items_count  = WC()->cart->get_cart_contents_count();

    if( $items_count < 3 ){
        $cost_rate = 2;
    } else {
        $cost_rate = $items_count;
    }

    foreach ( $rates as $rate_key => $rate ){
        $taxes = [];
        $has_taxes = false;
        // Targeting "flat rate"
        if ( 'flat_rate' === $rate->method_id ) {
            // For 1, 2 or 3 items
            if ( $items_count <= 3 ) {
                $rates[$rate_key]->cost = $rate->cost * $cost_rate;

                // Taxes rate cost (if enabled)
                foreach ($rates[$rate_key]->taxes as $key => $tax){
                    if( $tax > 0 ){
                        $has_taxes = true;
                        $taxes[$key] = $tax * $cost_rate;
                    }
                }
                if( $has_taxes )
                    $rates[$rate_key]->taxes = $taxes;
            }
            // For more than 3 hide Flat rate
            else {
                // remove flat rate method
                unset($rates[$rate_key]);
            }
        }
    }
    return $rates;
}
```

And save…

2) In Your shipping method settings, **you will need to set `60` as your "Flat rate" cost** and SAVE.

You need to keep your minimal amount for "Free shipping" method.

You are done. Tested and works.